# Reading multiple objects in S3 with changing path name based on current date and time

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to read multiple log file in s3.

The folder structure is:

`s3://FOLDERNAMEL1/FOLDERNAMEL2/FOLDERNAMEL3/FOLDERNAMEL4/YYYY/M/DD/T/*_log.txt`

FOLDERNAMEL1 to FOLDERNAMEL4 are fix but YYYY/M/DD/T/*_log.txt changes depending on date on current date and time.

And there are 5 log files that I need to read on this path at a single time.

I am new to python. I tried using asterisk to read files. At least 1file but I am getting an error message.

CODE:

```
obj = s3.Object("FOLDERNAME1", "FOLDERNAMEL2/FOLDERNAMEL3/FOLDERNAMEL4/*")

body = obj.get()['Body'].read()

print(body)
```

ERROR:

```
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied",
```

"errorType": "ClientError",

But when using complete path of file it can read file successfully so this is not an access issue.

```
obj = s3.Object("FOLDERNAME1", "FOLDERNAMEL2/FOLDERNAMEL3/FOLDERNAMEL4/FILENAME")

body = obj.get()['Body'].read()

print(body)
```

So, I think my question is how can I call the file when the path changes depending on time it was executed? By the way, I am running this python on a lambda function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to read multiple files simultaneously with one API call.

You will need to call `list_objects_v2(Prefix='FOLDERNAMEL2/FOLDERNAMEL3/FOLDERNAMEL4/')` to obtain a list of the objects in that directory, then read the contents of each object individually.